# windows universal app pdf viewing

Tags: windows, pdf, win-universal-app, windows-10, universal

I'm trying to design a Windows 10 Universal application which can download pdfs from online and open them natively in the application while retaining the functionality to fill them out (obviously only for pdfs that normally have such functionality). Is this possible as of now (using either microsoft's own or third party products) ?

Comment: Have you tried using Flash? *tongue in cheek*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Windows 8.1 there is a API for rendering PDF documents. You can find a SDK-Sample here - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-sample-85a4bb30/

The problem is: The API render the PDFs to an BitmapImage. You will loose all the functionality to edit forms, it´s viewing only. For Windows 10 there is no aditional way to handle pdfs.

Here is a list of third party controls, who maybe can do the trick. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2013/02/15/pdf-view-components-for-windows-store-apps-winrt-xaml-c.aspx

This stuff is created for windows 8.1, but should work for windows universal as well.

Comment: This is what I suspected, I was hoping there was some Windows API I just hadn't heard of. Thanks!